# How can I remove html tags from a javascript file on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a game in html/javascript. I kept the html and the javascript in 2 different files, and locally the program works fine, so I attempt to place the files on my website as two webpages http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2 is the html and http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2_js is the javascript file (created with sublime text 2 and saved as a .js) the html references the javascript file with the following tag

```
<script src="/coffee_brewers_v2_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but unlike my local tests, the online version doesn't receive the javascript file.

I believe this is because the javascript file is being interpreted as html when you view the source of the javascript page you can see html that I did not write.

What's going on? How can I fix this? (other than putting all the javascript code in the html file)

EDIT: I have renamed the javascript file coffee_brewers_v2.js

and change the html tag in the html file to:

```
<script src="/coffee_brewers_v2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem persists

EDIT 2: I'm now noticing even the .html has paragraph tags that I didn't put there. I'm using droppages(dot)com (dont have the reputation to post a 3rd link in one question) via dropbox to host the webpages could they be the problem?

EDIT FINAL: Droppages was forcibly interpreting every file as an html. I figured out how to stop that from their website. And it all works perfectly. You can play my awful game as a reward for sticking it out with me (it works!)

Comment: Why don't you use the regular `.js` extension?

Comment: I never understand why people like to make things more complicated. Using the normal file extension won't give you errors.

Comment: I do, the file in question is coffee_brewers_v2_js.js the extra "_js" was me wondering if the html and the js having the same file name with different extensions could somehow be the problem (it isnt)

Comment: Then why don't you reference it with the full file name? `coffee_brewers_v2_js.js`

Comment: Just take off the `/` out.

Comment: To clear confusion over naming, I've changed it to something more agreeable, the problem unfortunately persists (See Edit)

Comment: I'll try that Filipe. I read on w3schools that you normally leave the / in.

Comment: No luck on the / solution Filipe

Answer (score 0):

The response from the server for the file `coffee_brewers_v2_js` is

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Cache-Control: private
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 23:49:43 GMT
  Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 19:06:44 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
  Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 23:50:43 GMT
  Content-Length: 6108
Length: 6108 (6.0K) [text/html]
```

which supports you assumption that is gets send as HTML. You may try to rename the JavaScript file to `coffee_brewers_v2.js` to make Microsoft's IIS happy. Most Webservers handle filetypes by the endings if not told otherwise.

Comment: said change has been made, I'll let you know as soon as it updates (usually takes 90 seconds)

Comment: To clear confusion over naming, I've changed it to something more agreeable, the problem unfortunately persists (See Edit)

Comment: Does it also now see http://wdixon.droppages.com/coffee_brewers_v2.js as a text/html ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, but you missed the .js extension in your code.

```
<script src="/coffee_brewers_v2_js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: To clear confusion over naming, I've changed it to something more agreeable, the problem unfortunately persists (See Edit)

Comment: You have your script tag inside of a p tag.  What if you move it inside your head tag or right above your body closing tag?

Comment: That's weird, that p tag shouldnt be there. It isn't in my local file, it just shows up there in the browser, what is going on?

Comment: I'm not really sure why it's adding extra p tag, but if you inspect your page, you also have extra p tag before the html tag on your html file.  i inspected it by using the Resources tab on Chrome inspector

Comment: I see the tag too, I have no idea why its being added. I'm using dropbox and droppages.com to host the website, could they be the problem?

Comment: I would see if you could start a localhost server and see if it hasthe same problem.  If it doesn't then the problem has to be with dropbox hosting.